QED Matrix element squared is negative
When considering the tree-level 2-to-2 process $e^-e^+\to\gamma\gamma$ in QED, one can find the matrix element (with t,u-channel)
$$
|\mathcal{M}|^2 = |\mathcal{M}_t + \mathcal{M}_u|^2 = \frac{2e^4(m_e^4(3t^2 + 14tu + 3u^2) - m_e^2(t^3 + 7t^2u + 7tu^2 + u^3) - 6m_e^8 + tu(t^2+u^2))}{(t-m_e^2)^2(u-m_e^2)^2}.
$$
When I plotted this on the $s,t$-plane, I discovered that for some values of $|\mathcal{M}|^2$ returns negative values. For example, if one fixes $s=5m_e^2$ and plot on $t\in{[-1,1]}$, $|\mathcal{M}|^2$ is negative. How is this possible, when the quantity is an absolute value squared?


$t \in [-1,1]$ does not make sense as $t$ has (mass) dimension $2$. 2. You have to take into account  the kinematically allowed range for the invariant $t$.


I am sorry, I should have specified that $t$ of course has mass dimension 2, $t\in[-1,1]$ in units of GeV. As $t=(p_1-p_3)^2=m_1^2+m_3^2 - 2E_1E_3 + \vec{p}_1\cdot\vec{p}_3 $, I see no reason that $t$ is not negative. However,  I am more interested in the second part of your comment, considering the kinematically allowed region. $s$ is chosen to be $s\in[4m_e^2,\infty)$, is there any easy way to check the constrained region? I have never had this problem before with other processes.

See e.g. https://pdg.lbl.gov/2024/reviews/rpp2024-rev-kinematics.pdf p.7.

units of GeV Those units are three orders of magnitude greater than the mass scale in the process.
